# Currency symbol with FlipClock.js

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I'm using two FlipClock instances on a web page: one is counting down during a 24-hour event, and the other shows how much money has been raised during the event. The first one is a clock face counting down and the other a general counter face, counting up. It would be great if I could add a currency symbol to the last one. Is that possible within FlipClock and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that setTime() accepts symbols as well so I'm just using that.